# htmlagilityPack: Web page doesn't return complete html

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Using htmlagilityPack trying to get all href links. But web page doesn't return all links.

I tried in browser and saw that until you scroll down the whole page it doesn't show all links.  Then I tried to resize (zoom-in) browser window so that all page contents can be seen without scrolling down. That moment all links appeared. May be java need to triggered....

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument Doc = web.Load("https://www.verkkokauppa.com/fi/catalog/438b/Televisiot/products?page=1");

foreach (HtmlNode item in Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='product-list-grid__grid-item']/a"))

{                                                                               
 debug.WriteLine(item.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));                      
}
```

One page has 24 product links but I get only 15 out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Network tab in chrome on that page. There are ajax requests to `https://www.verkkokauppa.com/resp-api/product?pids=467610`. So products are loaded using javascript.

You can't just trigger javascript here. HtmlAgilityPack is an html parser. If you want to work with dynamic content you need browser engine. I think you should check [Selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtH4i7CPg1M) and [phantomjs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oCm6S5zGdE).

Comment: thanks, how to check what is the API for this product range.

Comment: You can check links to intro videos from the answer

Comment: Or you can try consume site API directly, I mean get JSON from resp-api endpoint

Comment: I can use JSON but how to get API, mean how to get all pids?

Comment: There is no clear way. To work with api directly you need to find out a way how to get these pids. The most straightforward way is to use `selenium\phantomjs`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your knowledge and experience can you help to find a way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193871/discussion-between-aap-and-mtkachenko).